# Wordpress PHP Server Script to send email

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to get a server script to use wp_mail() and send an email to a user. I am doing this as part of a password reset routine, and calling the script with Ajax from the user's side.

I am getting the following error from my server script:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_mail() in /var/www/abc-php/pwd.php on line 57
```

I cannot seem to find an answer to my question, so maybe I am asking incorrectly. Is what I am doing possible?

My server script (pwd.php) contains:

```
<?php

    $setFromId = "info@abc.com.au";
    $setFromName = "Info @ abc";
    $replyToId = "info@abc.com.au";
    $replyToName = "Info @ abc";

    $sendToEmail = base64_decode($_GET["ste"]);   //the URL in AJAX call contains base64 encoded data
    $resetPwd = base64_decode($_GET["rp"]);
    $resetSalt = base64_decode($_GET["rs"]);
    $param = $_GET["var"];

    $username = "xxxxxxxxx"; 
    $password = "xxxxxxxx";   
    $host = "localhost";
    $database = "xxxxxxxxx";
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    } else {
        switch ($param) {
            case "PWDRES":                                              // Query 1: Current Logged In Partner Details 
                $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                    echo '<p>Unable to connect to the server at this time to update and send password. Please contact SMA for help or try again.</p>';
                } else {

                    $myquery = "UPDATE abc_users
                                SET `password` = SHA2('" . $resetPwd . $resetSalt . "', 512),
                                    `salt_value` = SHA2('" . $resetSalt . "', 512)
                                WHERE email_user_id = '" . $sendToEmail . "'";

                    mysqli_query($mysqli, $myquery);

                    if($mysqli->affected_rows >= 1) {

                        $headers = 'Reply-To: <' . $replyToName . '> ' . $replyToId;
                        $subject = "Password Reset - Confidential";
                        $body = "Subject: " . $subject . "<br/><br/>Your new password is: <br/><strong>" . $resetPwd . "</strong><br/><br/>Please ensure you reset this password next time you log in.";                        
                        $mail = wp_mail($sendToEmail, $subject, $body, $headers);
                        echo "Password was successfully reset and sent to " . $sendToEmail;

                    } else if($mysqli->affected_rows == 0) {
                        echo "No user id row was updated in the process of resetting password. Please try again.";
                    } else if($mysqli->affected_rows < 0) {
                        echo "There was an SQL error updating the user id password table. Please contact SMA for help.";
                    };
                };
            break;

                    case "OTHER1"
                    etc, etc, etc...
        default;

        };
    };

    unset($con);    
    unset($myquery); 
    unset($mysqli); 

?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where you put your `pwd.php` file ???
in project root directory or theme's root directory ???

Comment: The php file is in its own folder with others for the site I have created. as in www/my-php/ folder. Does this influence the server's ability to reference WP functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are not including Wordpress, so you are not using it at all (and it isn't including its libraries).

Plus, this is unrelated to the question, but you have a weakness in your code :
Any users can define the recipient of the email.

Comment: Hi Loic, thanks for the reply. The email address is used as the ID in the system and is fed to the server via URL from a javascript form at the client end. The checking for validity of email happens on that page. How do I include Wordpress function for mail on the server script?

Comment: use this at the beginning of your file:
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
Give plus to Akshay.

Comment: Hi Loic, although your suggestion is slightly different to Akshay (i.e.: without underscores in the FILE piece), the result is the same, 500 Internal Server Error. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Ah, so rather newbie here... where do I find the logs? The implementation is on EC2 on Ubuntu x64 12.04 on LAMP. Thanks!

Comment: It should be in the /var/log directory.
There should be a folder named "apache" or "httpd" there.
And inside it, an error.log.

Comment: [Thu Feb 27 05:22:49 2014] [error] [client 124.184.9.209] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant FILE - assumed 'FILE' in /var/www/abc-php/pwd.php on line 2
[Thu Feb 27 05:22:49 2014] [error] [client 124.184.9.209] PHP Warning:  require_once(./wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/abc-php/pwd.php on line 2
[Thu Feb 27 05:22:49 2014] [error] [client 124.184.9.209] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required './wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/sma-$

Comment: If I read correctly it cannot find "/wp-load.php" as the script is running from "/www/abc-php/" folder. Am I correct? How do I prefix it to go back to root dir of site to look for wp-load.php? Thanks!

Comment: I changed the statement to require_once( dirname(FILE) . '././wp-load.php' ); and now it tells me it has sent the email! But the email has not arrived at my address... how do I check this in the PHP script. Is there a way to check if something else is stopping the email going?

Comment: you could check your mail server logs.

Also, ././ == ./

Comment: Hi Loic, or I could check JUNK MAIL folder!! It worked!! You rock!! Thanks for the patience and help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `wp-load.php` in your file....

Just put this in top of your file.

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
```

Comment: Hi Akshay, thanks for this. I now get internal server error 500... it does not like the addition. Should I be sending mail in a different way from the Server script?